# Handle null model in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my Action that return profile pic detail of user

```
 public ActionResult Avatar(int id)
 {
     // var userid = int.Parse(User.Identity.Name);
     var model = _profilePic.GetProfilePic(id);
     if (model == null)
         model = new ProfilePic {UserID = id};

     return PartialView(model);
 }
```

In view i want to access `@Model.UserID`. But getting exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Model

```
public class ProfilePic
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePicID { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string PhotoThumb { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model Namespace.Entity.ProfilePic



 <label>@Model.UserID</label>
```

Comment: Are you defining `@model` in the partial view?

Comment: yes as '@model MyNamespace.Models.ProfilePics'

Comment: it always has a value

Comment: There's something you're not telling us.  It seems doubtful that the error is occurring at `@Model.UserID`.

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace?

Comment: this line - var model = _profilePic.GetProfilePic(id); does it return an object that is not null?

Answer (score 0):

Just explicitly test for null:

```
@model Namespace.Entity.ProfilePic
if (Model != null)
{
    <label>@Model.UserID</label>
}
```

Then, it will only try to access `UserId` if there's an actual instance to access it it on. You can also utilize a `else` block to provide a default fallback.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure that `GetProfilePic(id)` returns a ProfilePic object. I think model might not be instantiated with a ProfilePic object when `_profilePic.GetProfilePic(id`) returns a non-null.

Comment: What? that will not work, it'll just spit out "Model.UserID" to the page.

Comment: Please ignore as I replied in a different context assuming model is being accessed in @using otherwise framework treat it as a string anything without @.